# Grunt Uglify produces code that browsers do not agree with

Tags: javascript, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am new to Grunt and to grunt-contrib-uglify. I have created a test JavaScript file:

```
function global(window) {
  window.test = alert("Test");
  test();
})(window);
```

When this is uglified, it appears as

```
!function(a){a.test=alert("Test"),test()}(window);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ug4n5jnc/)

I am confused by two things:

- Why is there a comma rather than a semi-colon between `("Test")` and `test`?
- How is it that this code actually produces the expected result?

When I run it in Chrome, an alert duly appears, but the console complains `Uncaught TypeError: test is not a function`. When I run it through JSHint, it reports: "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression."

Is grunt-contrib-uglify taking advantage of aspects of JavaScript that neither Chrome nor I fully understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It causes an error in Chrome because your original code is invalid. What you are actually doing is assign the result of `alert("Test")` to `window.test`. `alert` returns `undefined`, so when you are attempting to call `test` later on, it references `undefined` instead of a function. You're also missing an opening parenthesis, though that didn't cause the issue here.

It looks like what you're trying to do is create a proxied `alert` function that will call it with a predefined input parameter. You could do this using the [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function, like this:

```
(function (window) {
    window.test = alert.bind(undefined, 'Test');
    test();
})(window);
```

The above should produce your expected result.

As to why it uses commas rather than semicolons, it's probably because the minified code validates to an expression (see [expressions vs statements](http://www.2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html)), and semicolons aren't allowed in expressions, while commas are.

Comment: At least my error led me to discover the [comma *operator*](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/).